# Start my app with device in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I built a reminders app, it wont work in background mode, and warns reminders via push notification.

But starting from the moment the User turn off your device (iphone or ipad) and turn on, my app is not this more in background mode, in which case reminders are no longer advised.

In this case, I like to find a way to make my app starts with the device but in background mode (the same happens with windows programs, android apps, and osx programs).

Comment: Are you using remote notifications or local notifications?  It isn't quite clear. Background refresh mode may work for you (set it in your capabilities), but you can't run an app full-time in the background like you can on Windows or OSX

Comment: Local Notifications.

Comment: Ok, then you can still use Background fetch mode but it make take some time after a device restart before your app is launched.

Answer (score 1):

You are focusing on the wrong question. The question you should focus on is, "How do I ensure that my app's reminders will be delivered to my users even after a device restart?"

The answer is to set a [Local Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW32) with a future delivery date, at the point the reminder is created, which of course is while your app is running. There is no need for your app to be running, in either the background or the foreground, for this notification to then be delivered at the specified time.

Answer (score -2):

check project setting in .plist set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is YES

Comment: So...Only this change can make my app start when device start?